# How to deploy an asp site with SQL Server database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a site with SQL Server database and I am having trouble deploying it to IIS.
The page in IIS cannot access the DB, I can see the page but I cannot login because the database is not accessible...

I can access the database when the site runs as debug from Visual Studio.

I guess it is a security problem.

How do I get it to work?

Thanks,

Comment: Can you please **show us** your connection string you're using??  Also: are you seeing any error? If so: **what** error??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal approach is to switch SQL Server from "Windows/Integrated Authentication" to "SQL Authentication". SQL Authentication allows you to [create a SQL login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx), which you can specify in your connection string like:

```
Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDb;User Id=MyUser;Password=***;
```

Virtually all hosting providers use this method.

Comment: is the poster using a hosting provider?

Comment: How do i change an existing db to "SQL Authentication"?

Comment: my server is already in mixed mode "Windows/Integrated Authentication"and "SQL Authentication". How do i change the db to have sql authentication?

Comment: @jkally: Add a user with rights on the database. (A Google search for "sqlserver create user" should give many tutorials.)  @Mitch Wheat: Most websites eventually move to a hosted server

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that the security principal that your IIS pool is running under has both a login on your SQL server and user access to the specific database.

If you are running in the Default App pool on IIS 6.0, the default account used is `NETWORK SERVICE` (if you haven't configured it to be something else)

[Application Pool Identities](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/)

Comment: And how do I know what's the  security principal that my IIS pool is running under?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance... Version 7.5